# How to increase the gap between legends in horizontal format?

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I have created a chart in which the legends are getting overlapped. I tried by increasing the value of `gap()`.
But it only works when the legends are in vertical mode.
I used the following code for the chart. Please help me out here to move the legends, so that they wont get overlapped. **currentanalysis** is the chart's name.

```
currentanalysis


.width(280)  
.height(190)  
.dimension(currentanalysisdimension)
.group(Incoming2)
.group(Outgoing2)
.elasticY(true)
.yAxisPadding(1)
.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["2","3","4","5"]))
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
.legend(dc.legend().x(0).horizontal(true).y(170).itemHeight(20).gap(0))
.compose([
     dc.lineChart(currentanalysis)
          .dimension(currentanalysisdimension)
          .colors('blue')
          .group(Incoming2, "Incoming/Download")
          .dashStyle([10,0])
          .renderDataPoints({radius: 4, fillOpacity: 0.8, strokeOpacity: 0.8}),

     dc.lineChart(currentanalysis)
          .dimension(currentanalysisdimension)
          .colors('orange')
          .group(Outgoing2, "Outgoing/Upload")
          .dashStyle([10,0])
          .renderDataPoints({radius: 4, fillOpacity: 0.8, strokeOpacity: 0.8}),

        ])


    .renderlet(function (chart) {
                    chart.selectAll("g._3").attr("transform", "translate(" + 15 + ", 0)");
                    chart.selectAll("g._2").attr("transform", "translate(" + 15 + ", 0)");
                })
 .render()
 });
```

I'm getting the result as:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following piece of code. This will work.

```
.legend(dc.legend() .x(10).y(195).itemWidth(120).horizontal(true))
```